# how can I merge a data into one?

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
1.1.1.1     Alcohol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.2     Alcohol dehydrogenase (NADP(+)).
1.1.1.3     Homoserine dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.4     (R,R)-butanediol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.5     Transferred entry: 1.1.1.303 and 1.1.1.304.
1.1.1.6     Glycerol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.7     Propanediol-phosphate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.8     Glycerol-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (NAD(+)).
1.1.1.9     D-xylulose reductase.
1.1.1.10    L-xylulose reductase.
```

I load it with read.table like this

```
df <- read.table("path to data", header=F, fill=T)
```

and I get the following data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 2L), .Label = c("1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.10", "1.1.1.2", "1.1.1.3", 
"1.1.1.4", "1.1.1.5", "1.1.1.6", "1.1.1.7", "1.1.1.8", "1.1.1.9"
), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 
8L, 5L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("(R,R)-butanediol dehydrogenase.", 
"Alcohol", "D-xylulose", "Glycerol", "Glycerol-3-phosphate", 
"Homoserine", "L-xylulose", "Propanediol-phosphate", "Transferred"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "dehydrogenase", "dehydrogenase.", 
"entry:", "reductase."), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "(NAD(+)).", 
"(NADP(+)).", "1.1.1.303"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "and"), class = "factor"), 
    V6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "1.1.1.304."), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I use fill=T because if I don't then it gives me error

```
df <- read.table("path/example.txt", header=F, fill=F)
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 6 elements
```

Is there a way that I load the data and have two columns? or bring the data together so that I will have two column in R?

Note that I can do that with read.delim but it will make problem with another code that I am using

my desire output is like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base `R`, you can use `Reduce()` with `paste()` and then trim the white spaces with `trimws()` to produce another `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = df[1], V2 = trimws(Reduce(paste, df[-1])))

> df2
         V1                                           V2
1   1.1.1.1                       Alcohol dehydrogenase.
2   1.1.1.2             Alcohol dehydrogenase (NADP(+)).
3   1.1.1.3                    Homoserine dehydrogenase.
4   1.1.1.4              (R,R)-butanediol dehydrogenase.
5   1.1.1.5  Transferred entry: 1.1.1.303 and 1.1.1.304.
6   1.1.1.6                      Glycerol dehydrogenase.
7   1.1.1.7         Propanediol-phosphate dehydrogenase.
8   1.1.1.8 Glycerol-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (NAD(+)).
9   1.1.1.9                        D-xylulose reductase.
10 1.1.1.10                        L-xylulose reductase.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but here is a possible solution:

```
# seperator is multi-space, but not possible in R
file_data <- "1.1.1.1     Alcohol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.2     Alcohol dehydrogenase (NADP(+)).
1.1.1.3     Homoserine dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.4     (R,R)-butanediol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.5     Transferred entry: 1.1.1.303 and 1.1.1.304.
1.1.1.6     Glycerol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.7     Propanediol-phosphate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.8     Glycerol-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (NAD(+)).
1.1.1.9     D-xylulose reductase.
1.1.1.10    L-xylulose reductase."

# change sep from 4 spaces to \t, which is identifiable. 
# replace textConnection(file_data) with your data file name
read_text <- readLines(textConnection(file_data ))
altered_text <- gsub("    ", "\t", read_text)

# parsing from altered text
df <- read.delim(textConnection(altered_text), header=FALSE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE)
df
```

The issue is your separator is more than one character (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/multiple-separators-in-sep-argument-for-read-table-td856567.html).

Alternatives would be to change the date pre-loading to have a common separator between columns. Otherwise read data as you have already, and add a data step to concatenate the columns 2 onwards in to 1 column e.g. using `paste`.

Comment: This is a better answer since it deals with the issue at hand during the creation of the object.

Comment: It depends if your seperator is always going to be 4 spaces. The good thing about your solution (paste method) is that you can handle any fringe cases if e.g. your data changes structure in the future. That said, best solution is to find out if you can get the data in a nicer format. Edit: thanks for the upvote :)